# How to rotate a player smoothly to another direction?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm just trying to rotate a player to another player's direction *smoothly*.

The easy way out is to disregard "smooth" and just use:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (player != target) {
            player.setRotation(Pitch, Yaw);
        }
    }
}
```

but what comes out is jagged movement, which I don't want. Is there a way to do this smoothly?

Comment: Did you tried by doing it with lot of step ? like each tick you send few changes

Comment: How would I do that? Like duplicate the Runtime a few times?

Comment: I'll make an answer

Answer (score 0):

To do that, instead of changing for somewhere to the given value, we will do it by step.

Imagine your want the player rotate in 1 second, so 20 ticks, you should do like that:

```java
public class HeadTurnTimer implements Runnable {
    private final Player p;
    private yaw, pitch;
    private addYaw, addPitch;

    public HeadTurnTimer(Player p) {
        this.p = p;
        this.yaw = p.getLocation().getYaw();
        this.pitch = p.getLocation().getPitch();
        this.addYaw = (yaw - dirYaw) / 20;
        this.addPitch = (pitch - dirPitch) / 20;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // add few to go to next value
        this.pitch += this.addPitch;
        this.yaw += this.addYaw;
        for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) { // your loop
            if (player != target) {
                player.setRotation(this.pitch, this.yaw); // set the actual values
            }
        }
    }
}
// somewhere else:
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(myPlugin, new HeadTurnTimer(player), 0, 0);
```

`dirPitch` and `dirYaw` are value that you want at final. Feel free refactor the given class as you want. Don't forget to cancel timer.

Value `0` means each ticks

Comment: Sorry but this still does the same thing as "player.setRotation(target.getLocation().getYaw, target.getLocation().getPitch". It's just like setting your game to 20 fps since it updates 20 times per second. This is kinda my problem. I'm just asking if it's possible to smooth that out, in gamer terms from 20 fps to 60 (Prob not but still curious)

Comment: You can't. You seems to want to turn it very fast, but with an animation, which is not compatible. What I showed can help to do the same as a real player which should be walking around